# Divinity immaculate trial

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I have done trial one and have put the levers in the correct position for trial 2 (double checked the positions for them online) but it's says I haven't done it correctly and the door doesn't open? Is this a glitch as I'v reloaded it before I entered the trial but get the same outcome...

Comment: According to the guide I read, you need to set 3 levers and flip a 4th one. I don't know where this 4th lever is though.

Comment: Done all that. The 4th lever is right next to the others but the door still doesn't open...am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the lever positions?